# how to add fonts to raspberry pi/GIMP

Tags: raspbian-stretch

So I have been working on a project, and I wanted to have a new "loopier" font than GIMP has. I downloaded a TTF font file from dafont and read that if you send it to /usr/local/share/fonts (Forgive me that may not be accurate but I know I had the right folder) I googled some stuff and spent an hour trying to do it. I first tried to copy it to that through the file manager, and it said I had no permissions to do so. So I tried to allow it by changing perms in the filesystem properties (I was gonna change it back, but now that I think about it, probably wasn't bright but I was an hour in and desperate) But I didn't have permission to do that either, go figure.
I tried to use my little terminal knowledge to ya know copy the file to the font file, and lo and behold it had a space in the name, I only know how to copy it with a regular name and I haven't done it in a long time so I forgot if I ever knew. Regardless I tried and it started spitting out errors.
If anyone can help with this, I would like to. I am trying to send a font to GIMP and I can't, so please post how to do something I forgot how to do

Comment: What’s the actual name of the font that you want?

Comment: MTF Memory.ttf along with a few other things I extracted in the zip file.

Answer (score 1):

Download and unzip the required font. I downloaded mtf_memory.zip and unzipped 'MTF Memory.ttf'.

I created a folder to hold fonts from the dafont website using sudo to give me permission to create the folder:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dafont
```

Then copied the ttf file to the dafont folder again using sudo to give permission for the copy:

```
sudo cp "MTF Memory.ttf" /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dafont
```

The font was then selectable in the text editor (leafpad):

[image]